# Built war file without java code

Tags: java, windows, maven, jboss, jax-rs

I was following the steps(provided to me by someone) to deploy a war file on the JBOSS on Windows which are as follows:

1) I created a folder  Verson3

2) Using windows command prompt, I went inside the folder Version3

3) I ran the following command and got BUILD SUCCESS

```
Y:\myusername\My Documents>cd Version3

Y:\myusername\My Documents\Version3>mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=com.pkg.DownloadService -DartifactId=DownloadService -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-we
bapp -DinteractiveMode=false

[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Maven Stub Project (No POM) 1
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] >>> maven-archetype-plugin:3.0.1:generate (default-cli) > generate-sources @ standalone-pom >>>
[INFO]
[INFO] <<< maven-archetype-plugin:3.0.1:generate (default-cli) < generate-sources @ standalone-pom <<<
[INFO]
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-archetype-plugin:3.0.1:generate (default-cli) @ standalone-pom ---
[INFO] Generating project in Batch mode
[INFO] ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Using following parameters for creating project from Old (1.x) Archetype: maven-archetype-webapp:1.0
[INFO] ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Parameter: basedir, Value: Y:\myusername\My Documents\Version3
[INFO] Parameter: package, Value: com.pkg.DownloadService
[INFO] Parameter: groupId, Value: com.pkg.DownloadService
[INFO] Parameter: artifactId, Value: DownloadService
[INFO] Parameter: packageName, Value: com.pkg.DownloadService
[INFO] Parameter: version, Value: 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] project created from Old (1.x) Archetype in dir: Y:\myusername\My 

    Documents\Version3\DownloadService
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Total time: 12.262 s
    [INFO] Finished at: 2018-02-22T17:16:11-06:00
    [INFO] Final Memory: 15M/161M
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

This generated the following directory structure:

```
Version3
|-- src
|   `-- main
|       |-- resources
|       `-- webapp
|           |-- WEB-INF
|           |   `-- web.xml
|           `-- index.jsp
`-- pom.xml
```

4) Next, I was asked to add the following and remove the JUnit related dependency code from the `pom.xml`

```
<repositories>
       <repository>
          <id>JBoss repository</id>
          <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public-jboss/</url>
       </repository>
</repositories>
  <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>  
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
      <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
      <version>2.3.2.Final</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
      <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
      <version>11.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

5) Another change I did was this in `web.xml`:

```
<!-- Auto scan REST service -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>resteasy.scan</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- this need same with resteasy servlet url-pattern -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>resteasy.servlet.mapping.prefix</param-name>
        <param-value>/rest</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ResteasyBootstrap
        </listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>resteasy-servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher
        </servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>resteasy-servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

6) Ran following command : `mvn clean package` where the pom file was. This created `target` folder and war file etc.

The thing I am wondering is that there wasn't any `java` file I used anywhere in the above process as per the instructions I received. But I do have a java file where 
a JAXRS webservice is defined and the package name mentioned inside that file is `com.pkg.DownloadService`. I am wondering if I should consider placing that 
java file inside the folder `DownloadService` and then run all of the above commands? Because building a war file without any web service doesn't makes sense to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should place your DownloadService.java under src/main/java/com/pkg. Following your directory structure, it looks something like:

```
Version3
|-- src
|   `-- main
|       |-- java
|       |   `-- com
|       |       `-- pkg
|       |           `-- DownloadService.java
|       |-- resources
|       `-- webapp
|           |-- WEB-INF
|           |   `-- web.xml
|           `-- index.jsp
`-- pom.xml
```

Comment: Thanks. I was wondering why `java` folder wasn't there inside `main` folder? I created `java`, `com`, `pkg`,`DownloadService` folders and then I placed the java file inside the `DownloadService` folder. The war file created was successfully deployed.